# Substitute for XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I learned to program in C# and later on picked up XNA. To my disappointment I found out that XNA isn't supported in Windows 8 anymore. So I guess XNA is dying out. I would love to find something similar to it. I would love to find something that deals with 2D graphics (3D is little too much for me now) kinda like XNA did, because that's something I can't do in bare C#.Just the managing of pictures and audio. Thanks for help.

Comment: It's not supported in windows 8 store apps. It can run on windows 8 desktop just fine.

Comment: SO is not here for library/framework/tools recommendation. And to answer your question, MonoGame is the continuation of XNA.

Comment: Unity3D http://unity3d.com/ ... http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/28/unity-game-engine-to-get-official-2d-game-support-and-a-built-in-ad-service/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNA **is supported** on windows 8 (in the **desktop**), just not for windows store apps.

If you want to create windows store apps then [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) was built to be a drop-in replacement for XNA. At the time of writing most is implemented, the notable exception being the content pipeline (you need to use XNA Game Studio to create the xnb files).

> MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4 Framework. Our goal is to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows & Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux and Windows 8 Metro. Windows Phone 8, OUYA and PlayStation Mobile development is currently in progress.

Comment: So XNA made game will still have no problems on Windows 8? If one would want to release a game in XNA today, there would be no problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yup that's correct. Xna games, like most programs will keep working on windows 8 (not rt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/). MonoGame is a cross-platform, drop-in replacement for XNA on Windows, Linux, WinRT, Windows Phone 7/8, iOS and Android.

It is a mature project and many commercial, successful 2D/3D games have been created using this library.